# How to get the current month?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm storing date in MySQL database with timestamp in (int) type column.

But how can I get this ( CURRENT) month current rows only?

What should be the SQL query to fetch desired data?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you aren't storing the date as a timestamp column?

Comment: you could try something like this:[stackoverflow.com - timestamp-as-int-field-query-performance][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738444/timestamp-as-int-field-query-performance

Comment: @john - "The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Not in mysql.
Exmple:`create table foo (ts timestamp); insert into foo (ts) values ( now() + interval 1 QUARTER); select * from foo;` returns (approx),2012-01-02 10:22:27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the year as well and you can use the date functions:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_field)) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_field)) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the timestamp of the first and last secondof the month and use sqls `BETWEEN`

Comment: Beware when using `BETWEEN` with dates, it can include dates outside the month you want to select. See one of my answers and the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095542/how-to-query-datetime-object-by-date/6096566#6096566

Answer (score -1):

```
$begin = strtotime(date('m/01/Y'));
$end   = strtotime(date('m/t/Y'));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= $begin AND date <= $end"
```

This is probably the easiest and fastest solution. Using a SQL function like `FROM_UNIXTIME()` can work, but it can lead to performance issues down the road.

Comment: Please share more details. `strtotime` does not look like something you can use in SQL